# Content Porter Issue - Import into Tridion 2011 from Tridion 5.3

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, content-porter-2009

I was importing Tridion 5.3 contents to Tridion 2011.
Exporting content was fine. But later when tried to Import the exported content below message showed and it failed

- Unable to upload package. Access to server could be restricted or package is too large.
- This request requires buffering data to succeed.
- Import was aborted

The file size tried to Import rages in 500KB
the MaxRequestLengthLimit in the web.config file is 1000 MB

Also checked to see if its the issue with user permissions tried with Admin , same error message and it closes.

Comment: Are you able to import even any smaller size package ? Which web.config (path) you have the 1000 MB limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MaxRequestLengthLimit` has nothing to do with the upload of large binaries for Content porter, which is most likely the issue you are encountering. From the [SDL ContentPorter 2009 SP2 documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ContentPorter_2009_SP2/task_CCFED8DFFA9A4E138DEA72FBDF4C18AD) it states you have to do the following:

1. If your Content Porter Web site runs on IIS 6, change the metabase property called `AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed` to a number that represents the maximum amount of bytes you expect to upload from Content Porter. A typical value might be `209752100`, that is, 200 MB.
2. If your Content Porter Web site runs on IIS 7.0 or IIS 7.5, then on the Content Porter server machine, navigate to the `Content Porter\ImportExportService\` subfolder of your Content Manager root location. which defaults to `c:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion` or `c:\Program Files\Tridion`).
3. Open the file web.config in a plain-text or XML editor.
4. In the root `<system.webServer>` element, add the following fragment (creating elements if they are not already present):

   ```xml
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209752100" />
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
   ```

   where the value for the `maxAllowedContentLength` attribute represents the file size you expect to upload (the value shown allows uploads of files of up to 200 MB).
5. Save and close web.config and restart IIS.